# show image in div on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am new to jquery and javascript. I want some picture in a div to change on click on another picture. I did look around here and found something similar to what i want but can't seem to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#changeImage').click(function(){
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $("#imageBox img").attr('src', 'image' + rel + '.jpg');
    })
});
</script>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="imageBox"><img src=placeholder.jpg></div>
<BR>
<a href="#" id="changeImage" rel="1"><img class="thumb" src="image1-thumb.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" id="changeImage" rel="2"><img class="thumb" src="image2-thumb.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" id="changeImage" rel="3"><img class="thumb" src="image3-thumb.jpg" /></a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

You can see it life here: http://www.thebruises.be/TEST/test.html

But as I said above it doesn't work; tried moving the ... inside the body but doesn't change anything.

Any help would be appreciated ... and as I mentionned above I has zero javascript/jquery skills.

Thx

Comment: Thx stratton & user 1479606; now it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using the same id for all `<a>` tags. an ID has to be unique within the page 
 your javascript is applying the on click function only to the first image
change id to class and your code should work
your code should look like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.changeImage').click(function(){
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $("#imageBox img").attr('src', 'image' + rel + '.jpg');
    })
});
</script>
```

...

```
<a href="#" class="changeImage" rel="1"><img class="thumb" src="image1-thumb.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" class="changeImage" rel="2"><img class="thumb" src="image2-thumb.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#" class="changeImage" rel="3"><img class="thumb" src="image3-thumb.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: No idea why but it doesn't seem to be working :|
Something else wrong with my code?

Comment: the code changes the image's source attribute to image1.jpg, image2.jpg, etc.  do these images exist?

Comment: yes they exist :( if not i should get a red cross no? I use IE 9 could that be the problem?

Comment: also try to debug your code. use console.log(this) within the click function to check if the correct link is clicked and if the function is even triggered

Comment: Edited my anser: it's because the jquery version you include doesn't exist. change it back to <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @stratton Not really. I've checked the link and it works. The problem is probably because he's not closing the script tag.

Comment: i did see that indeed ... didn't close the script tag ... was gonna try that one in a second

Comment: Thx both of you ... using this code now ... can i give rep to you too user1479606 ...?

Comment: and i was the one who pointed the class/id issue out out so we kind of both helped him... i gave you an upvote too so don't worry

Answer (score 1):

Change your `id="changeImage"` to `class="changeImage"` since id is unique.

Then you can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over all of your anchors with class `changeImage`:

```
$('.changeImage').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(){
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        $("#imageBox img").attr('src', 'image' + rel + '.jpg');
    })
});
```

---

Copy and paste this to your jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.changeImage').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function(){
            var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
            $("#imageBox img").attr('src', 'image' + rel + '-thumb.jpg');
        })
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7b66p/1/)

Comment: No idea why but it doesn't seem to be working :|
Something else wrong with my code?

Comment: does that really make a difference to what it was before?

Comment: @stratton look carefully and you'll see that the src of the images are different

Comment: the image1.jpg, etc exists in the same dir as the -thumb.jpg ... i suppose that -thumb isn't necessary ... could it be something in my html code or something?

Comment: @ThierryMartens I cannot see you using each in your site

Comment: i am using the code above just changed the -thumb.jpg to .jpg

Comment: I don't know why it's not work as you can see it's working in my demo. Can you update your site with my suggested code, I'll take a look.

Comment: @ThierryMartens It is probably because you're not closing the script tag after include your jQuery library and you should add doctype to your site: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`. Add that doctype in the first line of your html file.

Comment: Actually i saw the script closing tag was missing after stratton's edit ... tried selecting both answers but i can't and i don't have enough rep point to up you user1479606 :| BOTH helped me out alot!
THX!!!!

Comment: @ThierryMartens it's ok. Glad it helped :)